# Which case to use in “fungieren als”?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

Which case should I use after *fungieren als*?

Should I write:

> Die Szene fungiert als einen Ausgangspunkt des Dramas.

or

> Die Szene fungiert als ein Ausgangspunkt des Dramas.

Comment: Hat das Drama denn mehr als einen Ausgangspunkt? Sonst würde ich "D. Szene fungiert als Ausgangspunkt d. D." schreiben.

Comment: So habe ich geschrieben. Ich moechte nur die Grammatik genauer verstehen, damit ich die spaeteren Fehler vermeiden kann.

Comment: Tofro geht mit seiner Antwort auch davon aus, dass es nur einen Anfangspunkt gibt. In Dramen können aber verschiedene Erzählstränge zusammengeführt werden, so dass man nicht mit Sicherheit von nur einem Ausgangspunkt ausgehen kann. Und meine Frage ist eine Frage der Grammatik.

Comment: Also brauchen wir keinen Artikel, wenn es nur einen gibt. Sonst müssen wir mit Artikel schreiben ? Danke für die Erklärung.

Comment: Wenn du ausdrücken willst, dass es mehr als einen Ausgangspunkt des Dramas gibt, sagst du *...fungiert als ein Ausgangs...* und legst beim Sprechen die Betonung auf den Artikel. Wenn es nur einen einzigen gibt, lässt man normalerweise den Artikel weg, *kann* ihn aber verwenden (was aber den Satz u.U. mißverständlich macht)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's to be used here is what is called a *Gleichsetzungsnominativ*.

This is used in sentences like

> Mein Onkel ist Arzt
>
> Picasso war ein Maler
>
> Er fühlte sich als Künstler
>
> Die Szene fungiert als Ausgangspunkt

typically used with verbs like
*sein, werden, heißen, zu sein scheinen, bleiben, gelten als, sich fühlen als, sich erweisen als, fungieren als*

And the proper case is, if not already clear, *nominative*

Answer (score 2):

The word ›als‹ ties the following noun into the predicate (like the verbs ›sein, bleiben, werden‹). A noun in the predicate always reflects its preceding case:

> *Dieser Kerl* **ist** *ein Idiot*.

The predicative noun (ein Idiot) reflects the case of the subject (dieser Kerl) which is nominative. You can do the same thing with ›als‹:

> *Dieser Kerl* war **als** *Präsident* nicht zu gebrauchen.

It doesn't have to be a nominative, however:

> Er betrachtete *diesen Kerl* **als** *einen Idioten*.