# Clarification on nominative versus accusative in some sentences

Tags: grammatical-case, accusative, nominative

I was wondering, in a sentence such as

> Das Haustier ist ein Hund

would *ein Hund* be nominative or accusative (making it einen)? It seems like it should be accusative because it answers the questions of "is what?", but I feel like one of my teachers once said something about sentences like this being accusative. Other examples would be:

> Mittens ist eine Katze, etc.

(even though there it would be eine either way)
Thanks!

Comment: Where did you read the rule that if something answers "is what?" then it should be accusative?

Answer (score 7):

In this sentence "ein Hund" is in the **nominative** because it is a **predicate noun**. It is a noun that restates the subject.
Predicate nouns can occur only with the verbs sein, heißen, werden, and occasionally bleiben.
Predicate nouns are also taken by certain verbs in combination with [*als*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/32530/which-case-to-use-in-fungieren-als/32552) e.g. *gelten als*, *sich erweisen als*.

Comment: There are actually some more verbs taking a predicative in nominative: *sich fühlen als*, *sich entpuppen als*, *gelten als*, *sich erweisen als* and some very rare forms of other verbs.

Comment: The use with *als* has been discussed here: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/32530/which-case-to-use-in-fungieren-als/32552