# Gender of indefinite article

Tags: grammatical-case

Is the indefinite pronoun "einer" here grammatically correct?

> Das ist sicher einer der interessantesten Fragen

shouldn't it be Genitive (= one of the)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clarification on nominative versus accusative in some sentences](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40766/clarification-on-nominative-versus-accusative-in-some-sentences)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's wrong, but not because of case. "Sein" takes a nominative, not a genitive; the fact that a genitive modifier *follows* later has no bearing on its inflection.

No, it's wrong because of *gender*. "Frage" is feminine, so a pronoun standing in for it has to be feminine as well, so "eine" is correct. (Note that in this case, the following material *does* influence inflection. Yes, concord is tricky. Imagine what we Germans could engineer if we didn't have to exert so much of our attention on inflection...)

Comment: Sprache findet im Unterbewusstsein statt; wir könnten also nicht mehr oder nicht weniger ingenieurieren, wenn wir eine Sprache wie Chinesisch (keine Beugungen, dafür fixe Wortreihenfolge) hätten.